# OSGi using SpringDM on Virgo, running from Eclipse, MAC vs Windows development

Tags: windows, osgi, eclipse-virgo, spring-dm

This question is more of type "has anyone experienced something similar before and if so, what was the issue?".

At work I use an iMac to do my daily programming. After some initial (and still occasional) struggles, I got my project running on Virgo server. Stand-alone or from Eclipse, both work.

I checked out the same code at home on my Windows PC, installed same version of Eclipse and Virgo. I took the same installation & configuration steps like on the Mac at work. I can get the project up & running stand-alone. However, when I try to get the project deployed from withing Eclipse, no matter what I try, some bundles would not deploy.

As one of desperate last options I even moved Virgo to a c:\v, just in case the path was to long. Still no success.

Did anyone experience something like this before? What was the reason? Any hidden configuration I might be missing?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at the `Virgo\work\org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer_<someVersion>\staging\global\bundle\` directory. Virgo tooling should normally deploy to this directory and invoke the deployer. maybe there are some issues. i suppose, you already checked the debug-output-logs? maybe it issnt a problem of deployment but something else.

Comment: Hi wrm, thanks for your answer. I will check the directory you suggest. However, it seems to be some kind of weird Windows issue (like path too long or something like that), as I managed to get the same project running on Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

Comment: A bit late but still a comment: I left the Windows struggle for a while to pick it up later. The real problem was not only Virgo but eclipse and workspace as well. I moved eclipse to c:\e, I moved workspace to c:\w\. Then there was another vague issue of missing bundles. The real problem in Eclipse was something else: I forgot to mark the test folders in Eclipse (properties > spring > test folders - or something like that). As soon as I did that, Virgo and my project were live on my Windows machine.